# Internet regret

Tags: graduate-admissions

So say if you graduated from a college that practices grade forgiveness, and you mention that you got forgiven at least this many, on a blog where PhD students appear frequently(without mentioning exactly the name of the college or my own name or the exact name of the company that I work for) can I be given a disadvantage when I apply to, say, another field of study, such as an MBA program? That is, could anybody identify it as me? Could anyone actually care, since I should only be reviewed of my candidacy through the required documents, not information that is omitted from them?

PS I did say what group of schools the college belonged to(ivy league, big 10, seven sisters et cetera), what industry I worked for. And I wrote the said post because I really wanted to find out what chances I had of entering certain programs given a certain kind of background (whether college name or certain kinds of experiences could override gpa, for instance)

Comment: Could you briefly outline what "grade forgiveness" is, please? From reading some basic information, it seemed to relate to retaking courses to improve one's grade. But then, having more than one chance to take any exam seemed pretty much standard to me, even across different cultures and university systems (the difference apparently being mainly whether the number of retries is limited), whereas "grade forgiveness" sounds a lot more lime an exceptional measure only invoked under special circumstances.

Comment: Periodically check, what others might find if they google for you (using your real name). Don't use your own name on posts what you don't want to find in this list many years later.

Comment: So later I implored the blog owners to do something about the post like a year later; it was after I had deleted the account from the blog. (I was not aware.that i needed to keep the account to prove the author was me and thus get it deleted and so forth). The blog owner was sympathetic and made a separate 'ungooglable' safe space where a few articles were. Apparently one other person had made the same mistake I had made.

Comment: Do you suppose this was enough to prevent the post from affecting my future?

Comment: Grade forgiveness is a real thing where colleges delete, for instance, courses you got a d or f in. On my transcript it is kind of obvious that 'something' happened in semesters where i had grades from a few courses; either I took less than usual and got grades from them only, or I took more courses and dropped/failed some. It could have been seen as dropping courses, but the thing is that on the post I said I 'failed one or two'.

Comment: You know that by clicking on "edited X hours / days / months ago", we access https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/114744/revisions , which list the editions made to your post?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own post. Thanks.

Comment: You're being paranoid. There is no identifying information in your post and literally no-one cares what your identity is. If you've spent the last 5 years being afraid that someone is going to track down your identity based on this post and then something horrible is going to happen, it's time to give yourself a favor and let go of your ill-founded and overblown fear.

Answer (score 12):

No, no one dealing with graduate admissions is going to search for comments you've made on the web, and even if they did they would not care about your "grade forgiveness" events. The other answers posted so far seem to have very strange beliefs about the time people on admissions committees spend on candidates, the amount of detective work they are inclined to do, and their opinions about students who re-take courses and improve their understanding.

Answer (score 5):

The **Top, Golden, Number 1 rule** of typing stuff that is going on the internet is "make sure, "**BEFORE SENDING**" that you are happy to see it in 5 weeks, months or years time...

If not, then **Don't** hit "**SEND**"...

If not, then be prepared to deal with the fallout - there are examples of people losing jobs due to holiday tweets or taking a "sickie" and then being seen in the crowd at the football or tennis etc...

I heard a story of this - before internet, where a student asked his father for money to buy textbooks and spent it on Rugby Final Tickets. He then got stuck in the toilets at half-time and as the TV cameras had nothing else to show - they showed the rescue of someone stuck in the toilet... His Dad was watching the match : cue conversation between Dad and son... ")

Comment: (+1) This rule applies even here.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is "out there". It can be found. It may be less likely that it would be associated with you personally. However, as with everyone, it is what it is. The fact that you talked about it doesn't change the fact that "it" is a part of your record.

Your best response is to "carry on". While you may have hand bad grades and the grades may have been "forgotten", the policies were set by others. But your record itself will be more relevant to admissions than anything you said about it. Even if the institution disguises some facts, you may still need to be able to explain gaps.

On the other hand, many successful people have lapses in their past that they have been able to overcome. Work toward that.

Play the cards you were dealt. Play them as best you can. Any applicant to a program needs to be able to detail to the admissions group why they are suitable. It is no different for you.